# export as .exe in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, exe

Is it possible to export my Java application to a `.exe` file?

So far I can only build it as a JAR.

There seems to be an option in the project structure to use `exe` if I choose JavaFX however doing this and attempting to build creates an error of access denied to the destination folder.

Comment: I guess my first question would be why do you want to do this?